# In R h2o.glm build regression with intercept only (Null Model)

Tags: r, regression, h2o, intercept

I was wondering how to build h2o.glm regression with intercept only (Null Model)

The equivalent in lm would be `lm(y~1, data = data)`

Thanks!

Comment: How do you anticipate using or interpreting the results?

Comment: I was replicating the stepAIC forward selection function, but using h2o.glm. And the y~1 is the starting point.

Comment: I don't see that there is a comparable model. The NULL model isn't very interesting in conventional glm, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

H2O-3 requires that when building a model, your: "Training data must have at least 2 features (incl. response)."

There are however functions like `h2o.mean()` or `h2o.sd()` that allow you to get the mean and standard deviation of a column in an H2OFrame, respectively, which might be of use to your task.